# ¿Por qué no centra el título en la página?

Tags: html, css

Como puedo solucionar este problema?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Con una imagen es practicamente imposible ayudar, necesitamos ver el código respectivo (HTML y CSS)

Comment: @Shaz sabes como puedo agregar codigo? no se como hacerlo.

Comment: Debes editar la pregunta, puedes ver más información sobre el formato en el siguiente enlace: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: Forma rápida: Copia tu código a la pregunta, selecciónalo, y dale al icono `{}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes poner la etiqueta de tu título dentro de un `center`.

```
<center>
    <h1>Tu título</h1>
</center>
```

Espero y te sirva.

Comment: La etiqueta center se considera obsoleta y se ha quitado del estándar HTML. Puede que los navegadores la sigan soportando, pero podría dejar de funcionar en cualquier momento. Lo mejor es no utilizarla.

Answer (score 1):

Si la etiqueta del titulo de tu pagina es un H1, esto debería funcionar:

```
<h1 style='text-align:center;'>Galería de fotos</h1>
```

Comment: Esta respuesta es una mejor práctica que la que fue aceptada.

Comment: @Shaz Sin embargo, usar el atributo `style` no es lo mejor. Para un mejor mantenimiento de la aplicación es mejor hacer referencia a un ID o una clase en un fichero externo.

Comment: En eso estamos totalmente de acuerdo, tan solo dije que es una mejor práctica que la respuesta aceptada, nunca dije que era la mejor opción o lo que se debería hacer.

Comment: Bueno, para justificar por que razón hice el style dentro de la etiqueta fue porque no sabia si tenia una .css que controlaba las posiciones del ajuste de las etiquetas, y ya con esto evitamos descomponer el css y que sea menos tedioso para el compañero buscar otras soluciones.